# how to convert buffergeometry to geometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am trying to convert Buffergeometry to geometry.
I am using three 0.134.0.
And I tried like this.
`let geometryconvert = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geometry);`

But I have got this error.

`Attempted import error: 'Geometry' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').`

What is the best way to convert buffergeometry to geometry.

Answer (score 2):

From r125, THREE.Geometry is deprecated.

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401

That is why you are hitting this error.

From r125 onwards, you can't do anything with Geometry.  You will need to work directly with BufferGeometry instead.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, we have preserved `THREE.Geometry` in the following directory: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/deprecated/Geometry.js. It can be imported as a ES6 module. But as you have pointed out correctly, you can't use `THREE.Geometry` with any core engine logic anymore. After a period of time, it will be removed completely.

Comment: @Diarmid Mackenzie

But now I am trying to export buffergeometry to stl with threejs-export-stl.
``exportSTL.fromGeometry()``function's parameter is geometry not buffergeometry.

Comment: When I export buffergeometry to stl with this function, the model is broken.

Comment: Not sure what threejs-export-stl you are referring to?
This one, perhaps?
https://github.com/Doodle3D/ThreeJS-export-STL

If so, it's not been updated for 4 years, and will need to be updated to work with BufferGeometry before you can use it with the latest versions of THREE.js.

There is an STL Exporter here that works with BufferGeometry, and may work better for you:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/exporters/STLExporter.js